# Script to scan through several directories, look for a file and copy it to a new name

Tags: windows, file-transfer, vbscript

Hopefully someone can help me out here. I need to clean up some data on a regular interval but short of doing it manually I haven't come up with a good solution.

Here is the flow that I go through manually.

I have a top level folder called "Data", under it I have several folders, around 100 that come and go. Under each of those there is a file called folder.jpg. There is also subfolders under this directory but I need it to stop at the root level.

Ideally, what it would do is search through each folder and look to see if there is a file called show.jpg in there, if there is ignore the folder and move on. If not, look in the same folder for a file called folder.jpg and copy it to a new file called show.jpg.

Sounds easy in my mind.

Comment: You've tagged this VBScript - does it have to be in VBScript, or will batch/PowerShell do? What version of Windows?

Comment: "Sounds easy in my mind." - What have you written so far?

Comment: PowerShell will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that should work in PowerShell, but I haven't done testing yet. This assumes your Data folder is in the root of C:.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Data\*\* | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'folder.jpg'} | ForEach-Object {
    $CurrentFolder = $_.Directory
    if ((Test-Path "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg") -eq $false)
    {Copy-Item $_ "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg"}
    Remove-Variable CurrentFolder
}
```

Breakdown:

The parameter given to `Get-ChildItem` tells it to return all objects which are separated from C:\Data by one folder level down.

`Where-Object` is used to filter those results down to just files named folder.jpg.

`ForEach-Object` is used to loop through the remaining results.

To process each folder.jpg, we first set a variable (`$CurrentFolder`) to contain the value of its folder path.

Then we use `Test-Path` to see if show.jpg is missing from the same folder.

If show.jpg is not found, `Copy-Item` will copy folder.jpg to show.jpg.

Cleaning up the `$CurrentFolder` variable with `Remove-Variable` is strictly optional, but good practice.

The script could also probably be cut down to just this, if you're looking for a "one-liner":

```
ls C:\Data\*\*|?{$_.Name -eq 'folder.jpg'}|%{$c=$_.Directory;if(!(Test-Path "$c\show.jpg")){cp $_ "$c\show.jpg"}}
```

`ls` is a built-in alias for `Get-ChildItem`

`?` is a built-in alias for `Where-Object`

`%` is a built-in alias for `ForEach-Object`

`$CurrentFolder` was shortened to `$c`

The result of `Test-Path "$c\show.jpg"` was negated (i.e.: TRUE will be FALSE, and vice-versa) by encapsulating it in `!()`. If an expression evaluates directly to a Boolean, and you want a code block to run on TRUE, you don't need to include `-eq $true` in the `if` statement.

`cp` is a built-in alias for `Copy-Item`

`Remove-Variable` was omitted. (Though you could use the built-in alias `rv` if you like.)

Comment: I was able to get it to run but putting parens around 'Test-Path "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg"' so it looks like 'if ((Test-Path "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg") -eq $false)'

Comment: BTW, I cleaned up my other "answers". Appreciate all the help. This made my day.

Comment: @JoshFink Ah, the parenthesis are needed sometimes too. Good catch.

Comment: can you update the original code when you get a chance. Thanks for all the help